# With the YouTube API v3 how can I get access to content duration, and genres? By search or get details

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I tried to use this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,contentDetails&{playlist_id}&key={key}&maxResults=50
```

and

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=YouTube+Data+API&type=video&videoCaption=closedCaption&key={key}&maxResults=50
```

It says in the documentation it is contentDetails.duration but this doesn't seem to be present in the data I receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the detailed information about a video in a playlist, you will need to hit the [Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) method for every video in that playlist with the `snippet` and `contentDetails` values for `part`:

Request:

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2C+contentDetails&id=AKiiekaEHhI&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response (for `id=AKiiekaEHhI`):

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/Qz22l3E04nR4kuY2SGE5M_d1BMM\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/8X_byN22HJTh5FJyoMH9bFGR_Og\"",
   "id": "AKiiekaEHhI",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-05-04T10:01:43.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCkvdZX3SVgfDW8ghtP1L2Ug",
    "title": "The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask With Glitches - Part 17: Going Against the Flow",
    "description": "Follow me on Twitter! http://twitter.com/swordlesslink\n\nFollow me on TwitchTV for live video game streaming! http://twitch.tv/swordlesslink",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AKiiekaEHhI/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AKiiekaEHhI/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AKiiekaEHhI/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AKiiekaEHhI/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Swordless Link",
    "categoryId": "20",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
    "localized": {
     "title": "The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask With Glitches - Part 17: Going Against the Flow",
     "description": "Follow me on Twitter! http://twitter.com/swordlesslink\n\nFollow me on TwitchTV for live video game streaming! http://twitch.tv/swordlesslink"
    }
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT17M30S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The duration of the content can be found as the object for the `duration` key in the `contentDetails` dictionary.

The `categoryId` maps to your video category, which you will have to look up using the [VideoCategories.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list) method.

Request:

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&id={CATEGORY_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response (for `id=20`:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoCategoryListResponse",
 "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/cVclmqPmb6Xbwij8SctXRUrSVhw\"",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/WmA0qYEfjWsAoyJFSw2zinhn2wM\"",
   "id": "20",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Gaming",
    "assignable": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The object for the `title` key in the `snippet` dictionary returns the String value of the video category that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you check [search resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search), you'll see its not in that response.

This was actually a feature request in: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4294

You can follow up that issue.

Comment: That issue is marked as `WontFix`.  How are we supposed to follow up on it?